# Lost access to Admin rights, account on Standard, need to get switched back

Tags: password

Good Day ma'am/sir,  I need help, and am not locating the right type of help. I just got my mother a new PC with Ubuntu on it, after initial setup and updates, all was operational...upgraded to 14:04 (newer one available) (and I have the disc that came with PC it is for Ubuntu 13:04, I believe) So the problem; I know the passwords, we set them up to work for her, the problem is in the User Accounts part, her profile (the only one set up) was switched from administrator to standard user, and now for everything and anything it will ask for administrator privilege and the password does not do anything, just spits back the password bar. I tried changing the password, I just can not get her account back to Administrator. If any help is able, it would make the world of a difference. Thanks for your time, Good Day,

Semper Fidelis 
Lt. Woods

Answer (score 0):

If that account is part of sudoers, try changing the password for root.

```
sudo passwd root
```

And give a new password. It could work if your account is in the sudoers list

Comment: Thank you for your input, however it only returned with (typed in- sudo passwd root)'Joyce is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.' I do appreciate your help. She is the only user/profile on the PC, it allows trivial stuff and Log-In with her password, just nothing to authenticate, nor the important step of changing her account back to administrator from its now standard level profile, the unlock button just returns unsuccessful. Anyway, Thank you for the assistance,

Answer (score 0):

I believe the command for changing a standard account to administrative is:

> sudo adduser [username] sudo

Where [username] is the name of the account you wish to change.  I think this can even work for the account you are logged into, but I've not tried it for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately it returns 'Joyce is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.' this is the result of 'sudo adduser Joyce sudo'
there is only one account set up on the PC, and it accepts her password for log-in and trivial stuff, but any authentication needed it returns the enter password bar, and just closes after the third attempt, and I aam positive of the password. Any other help is grateful.

Semper Fidelis
Lt. Woods